# Provide all dependencies for @InjectMoks objects with Mockito that can not provides with @Mock

Tags: testing, kotlin, mockito, androidx

**Senario**

I am going to Test my activity with AndroidUnittest and **Mockito**.  I have two classes that wanna mock with **Mockito**. (Really i do not care inside these two class i just wanna mock them and see activity interactions with them) 
One is **viewModel** and other is **SomeManager**. Both have complicated dependencies that finally needs context which all dependencies provided by dagger. Some of them has module and some of them has constructor injection. I just share my ViewModel and if i can find a solution it will also works for my Manager.

```
class HomeActivityViewModel @Inject
internal constructor(
    @Named("io") val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
    private val navigationDrawerManager: NavigationDrawerManager,
    private val userAccountManager: UserAccountManager, //Needs context
    private val tokenManager: TokenManager, //Needs context
    private val context: Context,
    private val authRepository: AuthRepository,  //It is a interface that Impl provided by dagger
    private val retrofit: Retrofit,
    private val userInformationRepository: UserInformationRepository
) : ObservableViewModel(), CoroutineScope {
```

And this is in test class:

```
@InjectMocks
lateinit var mockViewModel: HomeActivityViewModel

//All needed in viewModel
@InjectMocks
lateinit var navigationDrawerManager: NavigationDrawerManager
@InjectMocks
lateinit var userAccountManager: UserAccountManager
@InjectMocks
lateinit var tokenManager: TokenManager
@Mock
lateinit var authRepository: AuthRepository 
...

@Before
fun setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
}
```

**Problems**

1. How to provide Context

I provided all complicated objects ( My viewModel and Manager) by `@InjectMocks` and simple dependencies by `@Mock` But at end i need Context that i think it can not provide by **Mockito**. So i do not know how i can provide context for that `@Mock` annotations. I just put

```
val context: Context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
```

but do not know how i can expose this to **Mockito** wire ups in

2. How to expose some custom mock objects to `@Mock` or `@InjectMocks` annotated objects

Also some of classes can not mocked like: Retrofit. So i have to create a mock and pass to that object that needs as dependencies. (Annotated by @Mock or @InectMocks) But i do not know how?! For example if i prepare Retrofit like this:

```
var okHttpClient = OkHttpClient()
var retrofit: Retrofit = RetrofitBuilderFactory.createRetrofit(okHttpClient)
```

How i can expose them to consumed by @Mock or @InjectMock items?